# Applying one of the Kinematic formulas to a 2D projectile question failed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I started learning Kinematics for fun at Khan Academy, and so far it's quite interesting. Anyway, I was reading about [2D Projectile Motion](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/two-dimensional-motion/two-dimensional-projectile-mot/a/what-is-2d-projectile-motion), and was trying to solve the second example myself. You can find it by searching `Pumpkin launched at an angle`.

**An air cannon is used to launch a pumpkin off a cliff of height $H=18.0m$ with an initial speed $v_0=11.4 \frac{m}{s}$ at an angle of $\theta=52.1$
What is the speed of the pumpkin right before it hits the ground?**

I tried applying the formula

$$\Delta y = v_{y0}t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$$

Now, I have the initial vertical speed, we know that the vertical acceleration is constant, so I've found $t=3.04$ and then plugged it into $$\Delta s = (\frac{v_0+v_f}{2})t$$ and found that $v_f = 3\frac{m}{s}$

Turns it it's completely wrong. Would love to know where my mistake was.

Another thing that bothered me: when I was calculating the time I ended up with a 2nd degree equation, which meant that one of the solutions for $t$ was negative, already suspicious. Is this a part of the mistake? Can that be, and if so, does it have a deeper meaning?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try breaking the launch velocity into its components. If initial velocity vector is $\overline {v_0}$ inclined at $\theta$ to the horizontal, it's horizontal and vertical scalar components will be $v_0\cos \theta$ and $v_0 \sin \theta$ respectively. Then make use of the equations of projectile motion. You've calculated time correctly.

Now to find the final vertical velocity, make use of $v_y=u\sin\theta-gt$. Now note that you have the final velocities in the horizontal and vertical directions. Simply calculate the magnitude of the resultant final velocity vector as $\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$ and you're done.

[image]